# why my inherit group permissions for dirs is not working?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, chmod, chown

On a Samba share we use for websites we force users to access as userX:www-data
We've intentionally limited permissions of the group to read and execute so only those dirs that really have a reason to be writeable by the group receive these permission.
We do that via a bash that sets:

```
chown -R userX:www-data 2771 /directory_with_write_perms
```

the initial 2 we understand has the same effect as a

```
chmod g+s
```

that we've also tried for this issue with the same result.

Now that dir is writeable and any new dirs or files created get the group correctly but the group still have no write permission (r-x)

I have read solutions using templates via ACLs support on the partition but we are trying to avoid that route.

Is it anyway to set permissions not only to inherit parent's group ID but also parent's write permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You realised the +s bit only get's you the group correct.

You can fix the umask with samba itself and the `create mask` parameter for your share.
Even better to really inherit, have a look at `inherit permissions`.

actually I would recommend to not use +s but do everything in the share config to have it in one place. See `inherit owner` for that.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

Comment: Still have to do some testing but at least on the Samba side that seems to solve the issue as well as removing a "directory mode = 0751" directory that was forced in the share. Thanks.